# Arrange list items in alphabetical order in a table, with list dividers as the initial letter

Tags: jquery, android, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

Using in jQuery Mobile and Phone Gap I have implement a table view. I set the list deciders manually as follows:

```
<ul data-role="listview">

       <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>

      <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>


      <li data-role="list-divider">B</li>

      <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Bwaaaat</a></li>

     </ul>
```

It's fine for small amount of data, but we are using bundle of data as list items.

I need to display items in an alphabetical order, even though I enter data in any order. (without setting it manually by hard code)

The fist letter of the words as the header in section.

Finally how do I set a theme/color for our list header?

Answer (score 1):

For sorting you can use [sorttable.js](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js) but this is for sorting the table,You will have to change it according to your requirment.

For theme you can use.....

```
<section  data-role="page" data-theme="a">
```

There is a good link for [custom theme](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/custom-theme-28-2-2011).I hope it will work for you.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/theme-control-jquery-mobile.html